# Flatpickr Time OnChange Double Event

Tags: datetimepicker, timepicker, flatpickr

**Problem**

When performing an "OnChange" event for a time only picker, I am always receiving a double event for the first instance.

From what I can see it is parsing the current time first and then the selected time.

This also means there is an issue when keying in the time manually on the first instance too.

**Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/ux2dy5th/

```
$("#start-time").flatpickr
(
    {
    noCalendar: true,
    enableTime: true,
    inline: true,
        onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance)
    {
        alert(dateStr)
    }
  }
);
```

**Desired Outcome**

Only one "OnChange" event is triggered, that being the time that the picker is changed to (through clicking or keying in). No "OnChange" event being triggered for the current time.

**Context**

I am aiming to have two time pickers (a start time and finish time), where the max and min are set by on change events. The start picker can never exceed the finish time, and the finish cannot be set earlier than the start time.